# Sinch: Call from Web getting 'HUNG_UP' automatically

Tags: javascript, video-capture, sinch

I am trying to integrate **Sinch** in one of our projects.
I am trying to call from **WEB to ANDROID** app.. 
The connection is getting **successfully established**. But **no video is displayed** and also **call is getting disconnected automatically** in 9 to 10 secs...
This is not happening when I am calling from Android App to Web.. 
I am following code from their Docs for Video Calling.

**Log for call:**

```
Notification { progress=0,  message="Successfully added proxy ICE candidate",  object=mozRTCIceCandidate}
Notification { progress=0,  message="Successfully sent JOINED",  object=g}
Notification { progress=0,  message="Call changing state to ESTABLISHED",  object=undefined}
Notification { progress=0,  message="Call was un-muted using unmute().",  object=undefined}
Notification { progress=0,  message="WebRTC: Connection state changed",  object=Event iceconnectionstatechange}
Error { name="SinchError",  domain=-1,  code=1001,  more...} // code: 1001, domain: -1, message: "Ice connection failed. Hanging up call!"
Notification { progress=0,  message="Call HANGUP Received",  object=undefined}
-- ICE failed, see about:webrtc for more details
MXPLog { message="Added meta data to MXP message",  object=r}
MXPLog { message="Identified Encoding Key",  object=r}
MXPLog { message="Split message into frames as needed",  object=r}
MXPLog { message="Identified Tx Channels",  object=r}
MXPLog { message="Transmitting [channel, frame]",  object=[2]}
Notification { progress=0,  message="WebRTC: Connection state changed",  object=Event iceconnectionstatechange}
Notification { progress=0,  message="WebRTC: Signaling state change",  object=Event signalingstatechange}
```

Why I am getting `Ice connection failed. Hanging up call!` error..??
I am using Mozilla Firefox to test functionality... 
Thanks in advance for your help. I am stuck here...

Comment: I have the exact same problem with latest chrome too. Did you find any solutions?

Comment: There's still the same problem today. In my case: 1. Android to Web: - Same network: Working - Different network: Working 2. Web to Android: - Same network: Working - Different network: ICE failed Calling from android can be accepted in both environment.And The video is fine. Calling from web also can be accepted in both environment.But when it's in different network.The video won't show,and log will say "ICE failed". I think it's because the web and android is using different ICE server.And the web's have some problem.

Comment: I have same problem, Everything working except what i need. That is calling from Android to Web calling. Any one having sample?. Help need. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I worked for hours trying to solve this, at the end I discovered this was caused when both web and android is on the same network (when coding they usually are). It seems sinch doesn't work on same lan.